# Getting MySQL to use index type "unique" with index type "index" as key for a query

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

`SELECT a.var1, b.var2, a.var3 FROM a INNER JOIN b on a.var3 = b.var3`

I'm using a query like the above that is exceptionally slow. In table a, var3 is a unique primary index, whereas in table b var3 is an "index" type index. Other than that, everything is the same with regard to the indexes. Also, both tables are the same type (InnoDB) and collation.

When I use EXPLAIN, I can see that var3 is a possible key, but not a key. The only thing I can think of is that MySQL will not use a key where a variable is unique (or primary?) in one table but not unique ("index" type) in the other? Could this be? Is there a way to make this work?

I also tried creating, in table a, another index on var3 of the "index" type, such that table a then had a primary unique index for var3 and also an "index" type index. Still, via EXPLAIN, it did not use var3 as a key.

The answer may be that when joining on a "unique" type index and an "index" type index MYSQL will not uses these indexes as a key. If so, that answer itself is helpful, as I've not otherwise been able to find that in documentation online.

Comment: Please add the explain output and maybe the table definition (the output of `show create table a` (and b), you can leave out the unused columns and indexes), so we can see the missing details. My guess is that you are misreading the use of the primary key ("all"), but for that, it's easier to just see the actual exlain output.

Comment: How many rows in each table?  Please show us the `EXPLAIN`.